# Updateable jsRender template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender

After the template is rendered i need to make changes based on a field inside the template. Here I have done a not working example : http://jsfiddle.net/DrZ25/3/

jsRender renders the template and changing each lines input field changes the `year` in the example, but if new movies are added to the list - no change is made

Any option to make this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `live` to bind the event on `input`.

```
$("input").live('change',function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var year = $(this).val();

    $( "#year-"+id ).html(year);
});
```

​

Check this working [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DrZ25/4/)

Comment: Actually, as of jQuery 1.7 you should be using `on()` instead of `live()`. http://api.jquery.com/on/